# PyTorch Inference High CPU Usage on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, pytorch, computer-vision, amazon-eks

**Problem**

We are trying to create an inference API that load PyTorch ResNet-101 model on AWS EKS. Apparently, it always killed OOM due to high CPU and Memory usage. Our log shows we need around 900m CPU resources limit. Note that we only tested it using **one** 1.8Mb image. Our DevOps team didn't really like it.

**What we have tried**

Currently we are using standard PyTorch load model module. We also clean model state dict to clean up the memory usage.

Is there any method to reduce the CPU usage to load PyTorch model?

Comment: Reason: OOMKilled relates to out of memory (OOM). Are you sure want to reduce CPU usage?

Comment: Sorry it is both, memory and CPU usage are high. So, if there is anything I can do, I want to optimize PyTorch memory and CPU usage.

Comment: Just to clarify your problem: you want to upgrade somehow PyTorch to use less resources or to tune resource limits for deployment in Kubernetes (it seems not appropriate for you, since you mentioned your DevOps team)?

Comment: Actually @AndrewSkorkin, let us try to tune up the memory first.

Comment: At first, I'm trying to optimize my PyTorch code to minimize CPU and Memory usage.

Comment: Hello @SatrioAdiPrabowo. Any updates?

Comment: Hi @AndrewSkorkin! Thanks for coming back! We found out that the CPU and Memory usage are tolerable after we stress tested it. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried limiting the CPU available to the pods?

```yaml
  - name: pytorch-ml-model
    image: pytorch-cpu-hog-model-haha
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "1000m" # Replace this with CPU amount your devops guys will be happy about
```

If your error is OOM, you might want to consider the adding more memory allocated per `pod`? We as outsiders have no idea how large of memory you would require to execute your models, I would suggest using debugging tools like [PyTorch profiler](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html) to understand how much memory you need for your inferencing use-case.

You might also want to consider, using [memory-optimized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/memory-optimized-instances.html) worker nodes and applying [deployment-node affinity](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/140_assigning_pods/affinity/) through labels to ensure that inferencing pods are allocated in memory-optimized nodes in your EKS clusters.

Comment: Hi, Allan. Yes, we also tried to set CPU to 900m. But it just for 1 image inference. This is my first time deploying CV model. Do you have any baseline for CPU or Memory limit?

Comment: @SatrioAdiPrabowo, 900 gets rounded to 1000m (1 CPU) haha

Comment: @SatrioAdiPrabowo, just realized that you guys might be facing a memory issue instead of a CPU issue.

Comment: I thought that too. Let me get back to you tomorrow!

Comment: Good luck mate!

Comment: Hi Allan, we found out that the CPU and Memory usage are tolerable after we stress tested it. Thanks you!